# Path is not a legal form VS2017/2019

Tags: visual-studio-2017, prism, visual-studio-2019

I have clean installed VS2017 and VS 2019 with both the .Net Core 2.2 and 1.0 tooling. I cloned the latest version of the prism repository found [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism). Upon loading the solution, (PrismLibrary.sln) Most projects do not load. Upon trying to load one, I get the following error :

[image: Error Message]

I have followed the path and the file exists as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get around this/ fix it so i can fully load the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out in the latest version of the library, the global.json specifies .NET Core 3.0 preview. Remove this and the solution will work.